# Unit testing asychronous UI code which does not know about XCTestExpectations?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, xctest, unit-testing

How can one go about unit-testing pieces of iOS code that work in a non-trivial graphical setup?

Consider for instance view controllers `A` and `B`, where `A` stacks `B` on top with `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. A unit test should check the behavior of a `C` that depends on the two view controllers being arranged like that.

`performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` works asynchronously, i.e. the unit test would end before it has completed its task unless one lets the unit test wait for something like an `XCTestExpectation`. But in a case like this neither `B` nor `C` is prepared to call `fulfill` on that expectation.

Is there a way forward in situations like this, i.e. for testing asynchronous UI code without ready hooks for calling `fulfill`?

Comment: This sounds more like something for UI Automation than XCTest. What are you testing with C in your example?

Comment: @psobko I want to automate (also) testing of UI code with XCTest. `C` performs a non-UI operation but for its operation on `A` and `B` to be in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that employing an integration test framework (such as KIF) is probably the way to go.