# How to execute some code after a *modal* segue is done?

Tags: ios, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation, segue

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310396/how-to-execute-some-code-after-a-segue-is-done/18310963) answer suggests registering a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` for receiving notifications about when segues are done. This should work in the case of push segues where originating view controllers have navigation controllers.

But how about modal segues? Can something like this (a callback to `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`) apply in the case of modal segues as well?

Comment: use unwind segue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: @Rimidalv can you please elaborate. E.g., how could in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419994/unit-testing-asychronous-ui-code-which-does-not-know-about-xctestexpectations) example `A` use an unwind segue for finding out that its (modal, animated) segue to `B` is done?

Comment: I recommend present view controllers manually. It allows you to do whatever you want and you gain all the control.

Comment: @orkenstein what do you mean by *manually* in this context?

Comment: @Drux, you want to show VC modally, right? Then manually instantiate your VC and call `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Comment: @orkenstein I see. Have you ever tried such manual (animated) presentations in the case of unit tests (as in my [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419994/unit-testing-asychronous-ui-code-which-does-not-know-about-xctestexpectations) question)?

Comment: @Drux, never. I think `completionBlock` might be helpful in your case.